# Verifying electric brake current with opto-isolated feedback

Tags: current, opto-isolator, sensing, isolated, low-side

<del>I would like to find a way to sense (or detect) current through an opto-coupler.
This opto is used to power an electromagnetic brake, but depending on the type of brake the current through it can range from 400mA to 1500mA.</del>I want an opto-isolated digital signal to verify current is within a specified range in an electromagnetic brake circuit. The electromagnetic brake current can range from 400 mA to 1500 mA.

How do I detect this current safely and provide an isolated signal to the microcontroller? It could also be a current present/not present detection system.
The reason behind this is somehow detecting that the brake is powered (current is flowing) or not.

Thanks!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do. Is the opto used between MCU and a driver driving a brake to turn the brake on and off, or is it used to verify whether the brake is being powered and send a status signal back to the MCU? To do both will require two optos.

Comment: What is an **electromagnetic break**? Perhaps a nap in a dark room? Or did you mean **brake**?

Comment: @Neil_UK yes, Neil, correct. I have a MCU driving an opto which is used to power the brake. If for some reason the brakecurrent isn't flowing I'd like a way to detect this so I won't fry my motors.

Comment: @glen_geek, thanks Glen, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: It is system with feedback. You better control the motor turns.

Comment: The opto-coupler is a one way trip in terms of information. You'll need a second optocoupler facing the other direction to return a signal about how much current is flowing.

Comment: @Drew, it's actually your second option that is being sought. The question is just badly worded.

Comment: @AlexEr, your wording is causing some confusion. How you are switching on the brake is irrelevant so leave it out of your question. Please check the edit I have made is correct and delete the strikeout text or my text as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most non-invasive way is to eschew the optoisolator idea and use a Hall current sensor. There are various options, from small QFN parts that have an input loop built into the chip up to packaged parts that you simply pass a cable through. LEM, Mexlexis etc. are manufacturers.

Output tends to be in the 100-400mV/A range so you'd also need a comparator or to use an ADC and make a decision based on the value you read. Make sure the DC drift is compatible with your application (that it cannot give a false indication at the minimum current).